# NORMAL DISTRIBUTION(PROBABILITY)

Tags: probability, statistics

A particular fruit's weights are normally distributed, with a mean of 271 grams and a standard deviation of 22 grams.

If you pick one fruit at random, what is the probability that it will weigh between 220 grams and 234 grams?

I began by finding the z-scores at x=220 and 234 = -2.31 and -1.68.
I then subracted these values and got -0.63. And used the analogy that  if z=1 is 0.34 then 0.63= 0.34x0.63 and got 0.2176, but the computer says I'm wrong.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Find $\Pr(Z\le -1.68)-\Pr(Z\le -2.41)$. If you are using old-fashioned tables, it is easier if you note this  is $\Pr(Z\le 2.41)-\Pr(Z\le 1.68)$.  So two numbers to look up in the table.

Comment: i just did for 2.32 and 1.68 and got 0.0363. still wrong.

Comment: Got it rounding error.

Comment: Good that you found the fix. My comment was only about the "theory." In addition, there is a need for subtraction, division, correct table-lookup or use of software. I do not like automated hw programs, they are too literal minded, and mark something that is only a tiny bit off as wrong.